# Check variable against specific line in a text file | Python 3.6.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, match, external

Pretend I am making an email script. The user has already made a username and password, which has been stored in a text file so they can log in later at anytime.

The user needs to be able to log in. I want python to check that the users input matches the information in the text file from earlier, on their corresponding line. Capitalization doesn't matter.

The **text file** that was created initially reads:

```
johncitizen
johnspassword
```

My python script should read something like:

```
##Reads text file
guessusername = input('What is your username? ')
guesspassword = input('What is your password? ')
if guessusername.lower() = lines[0] and guesspassword = lines[1]:
    ##Grant access
```

I don't mind if capitalization is wrong, as long as the string itself matches up

Comment: 1. reading the text file

Comment: 2. checking the specific line to the input

Comment: Can you describe what's not working the way you expect? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: This kinda works but depends on how you open the file. As mentioned, a running test script (just add the open) and the  error helps us.

Comment: It just ends the script with no errors. I have code that follows but nothing works. i expected at least an else statement to show, but nothing

Answer (score 0):

Before first of all, what you are doing with plain text password storage is ill-advised.  You should be using hashing+salting, or even better, pick a decent framework to work in and learn from how they do it.

First of all, your data storage format should be more record like:

```
user_id<tab>username<tab>password
user_id<tab>username<tab>password
user_id<tab>username<tab>password
```

In that case, you are able to read the file like this:

```
username = ... #user input
password = ... #user input

found_user_id = None

with open('pass.txt', 'rt') as f:
  for line in f:
    fields = line.split("\t")  
    if fields[1] == username and fields[2] == password:
      found_user_id = fields[0]
      break

#okay, here if found_user_id is not None, then you have found them
#if it is None, then you did not find them.
```

Truly, a database is much more useful than a text file, but this is how it works!